# linkedin-j fetching all network updates

Tags: linkedin-api

I am using linkedin-j for fetching linkedin data

```
        Set<NetworkUpdateType> set = new HashSet<NetworkUpdateType>();
        set.add(NetworkUpdateType.SHARED_ITEM);

        Network network = client.getNetworkUpdates(set);
```

and it returns only 10 my own network updates. How to get all the public updates (not necessarily my own network connections) using these linkedin apis?

Answer (score 2):

Try like this,

```
Set<NetworkUpdateType> set = new HashSet<NetworkUpdateType>();
set.add(NetworkUpdateType.SHARED_ITEM);
Network network = client.getNetworkUpdates(set,1, 50);
```

Here First argument is START and second argument is END.

So you will get 50 results.

> Total :102
>   Start :1
>   Count :50

You can iterate over Total. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get your updates and updates of your first degree connections using the LinkedIn APIs, but you cannot get all updates across all people.

Comment: you mean using linkedin-j or linkedin itself does not all to get network updates beyond first level?

Comment: hi I need to gey my first degree connection update by the particular user

Comment: is it possible to get the network updates of particular user in linkedin-j